# Laravel how to date minus date and get minutes

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to date minus date and get minutes in blade. 
**Example:** 2018.07.20 13:00 - 2018.07.20 12:00 = 60minutes.

```
$match->updated_at->dateTime()
$match->played_at->dateTime()
```

updated_at minus played_at and get minutes.

Do i need use carbon? Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)

```
$updatedAt = Carbon::parse($match->updated_at);
$playedAt = Carbon::parse($match->played_at);
echo $updatedAt->diffInMinutes($playedAt);
```